# Is cascade removing by default in many-to-many relation?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to delete entities separately, without cascading. I wrote this to avoid cascading, but there's no apparent change.

```
ALTER TABLE License_To_Device DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_License_has_Device_Device1;
ALTER TABLE License_To_Device
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_License_has_Device_Device1
FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES Device (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE License_To_Device DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_License_has_Device_License1;
ALTER TABLE License_To_Device
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_License_has_Device_License1
FOREIGN KEY (license_id) REFERENCES License (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =
    {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "License_To_Device",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "license_id", nullable = false),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "device_id", nullable = false)
)
private List<DeviceEntity> devices;
```

Comment: So, what is the question? What exactly doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: @ Serghey Bishyr i removed cascade but i still have cascade remove (but i don`t want it)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Improved grammar; tightened wording.